# Not being able to display value from json data into chart js

Tags: reactjs, api, charts, chart.js, state

I am using react js. I want to make a chart using `chartjs` from the data I fetched from the api. Here, I just want to plot the chart between the below two arrays.

```
  symbolsdateforchart: []
  closingdateforchart: []
```

But, I am not sure how to use the value of these (please have a look at my code) since it has not been assigned yet, and the value get assigned in `componentDidMount()` and I making my chart inside `this.state`. Is there a better way to make the chart using `chartjs` between the above two array I mentioned. Or can I make this work  somehow? Any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
 import React from "react";

import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import Chart from "./Chart";

export default class Symbols extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      symbolsdateforchart: [],
      closingdateforchart: [],
       search: "",
      symbol: this.props.location.symbol,

     //here I am making my chart

      chartData: {
        labels: ["how to add the data of symbolsdateforchart here"], //and here I know the data is not yet assigned to symbolsdateforchart: [], so not sure how to make it work
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Closing price",
            data: ["how to add the data of closingdateforchart here"], //and here I know the data is not yet assigned to closingdateforchart: [], so not sure how to make it work
            fill: false,

            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255,99,132,0.6)",
              "rgba(54,162,235,0.6)",
              "rgba(255,206,86,0.6)",
              "rgba(75,192,192,0.6)",
              "rgba(153,102,255,0.6)",
              "rgba(255,159,64,0.6)",
              "rgba(255,99,132,0.6)",
            ],
          },
        ],
      },

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let symbolsdate = [];
    let closingprice = [];

    fetch(`http://131.181.190.87:3001/history?symbol=${this.state.symbol}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())

      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        for (const dataobj of json) {
          let tempsymbolsDate = dataobj.timestamp.split("T")[0];
          let tempclosingPrice = dataobj.close;
          let tempArray = tempsymbolsDate.split("-");
          tempsymbolsDate =
            tempArray[2] + "/" + tempArray[1] + "/" + tempArray[0];

          symbolsdate.push(tempsymbolsDate);
          closingprice.push(tempclosingPrice);
        }
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          items: json,
           //here the value get assigned for them
          symbolsdateforchart: symbolsdate,
          closingdateforchart: closingprice,
        });
      });

  }


  render() {

    return (
      //here I just print the table using the api I fetched in omponentDidMount()

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can't access the data in constructor from the same object since it's not initialized yet,

What I would suggest is to leave labels and data as an empty arrays in your constructor and then in componentDidMount when updating the state just update the label and data from chart as well.

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidMount()` you can update state variable `chartData` as

```
this.setState({
   isLoaded: true,
   items: json,
   chartData: {
     labels: symbolsdate,
     datasets: [{...this.state.chartData.datasets, data: closingprice}]
   }
});
```

Better is to separate dynamic part from static. Store static data like `backgroundColor` outside of state & provide statically in HTML of `render()` while, use state variables for dynamic data.

Comment: sorry, this does not work for me. Since it makes no difference. Here you are setting the `charData` to the values, but the thing is this.state get called first and the values are still empty

Comment: As the values are getting populated from API, in constructor phase it will be empty. You will have to update in other life cycle methods like `componentDidMount()` or `getDerivedStateFromProps()`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? If you can add it in your answer?